# Regex in request body not working for WireMock

Tags: java, regex, junit, wiremock

I am using WireMock to mock a third party response for a test case.

Here is how I am trying to write the stub -

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlMatching("/v1/url/([0-9]*)"))
    .withRequestBody(matching("\\{\"id\": \"([0-9]*)\",\"type\": " + "\"mytype\"\\}"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withStatus(200)
    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .withBody("{\"message\": \"Success Response.\",\"warnings\": []}")));
```

I can see the mapping populated when I make the call to

```
/__admin/mappings
```

But I get a 404 Not Found response when I try to make a POST call with below url and request body -

```
POST URL - /v1/url/12
Request Body - 
{
    "id": "12",
    "type": "mytype"
}
```

Please help me understand where I am wrong in stubbing the request.

**Note - I am intending to stub a POST call which has id in the URL (where I a using the regex for the same), and the same id should is expected in the request body for the id attribute.**

Comment: try matching("\\{\\s+\"id\":\\s+\"\\d+\",\\s+\"type\":\\s+\"mytype\"\\s+\\}")  ?

Comment: Maybe try a JSONPath match instead? Regexes over JSON documents are tricky because of whitespace and escaping.

Comment: Or, use [CustomRequestMatcher](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#custom-request-matchers). Few more lines of code but in my opinion a bit more maintainable and friendly. Note also, that you just got a response from the author of Wiremock... :)

Comment: Thanks @treesong. That worked. It was the white spaces issue.

Comment: You may want to post an answer with the solution here and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it as being the correct answer for your question.